Is there an algorithm for turning a pixelated path into a set of vectors and curves?
I have made a pathfinding program for my robotics team, and it uses Dijkstra's Algorithm (will change to A* eventually) to get the fastest path between two points. It outputs a list of points in the path, but they are on a pixelated grid, and I need to translate them to robot motion. How would I be able to build an algorithm to turn this into a collection of vectors and curves so that the robot can make efficient movements?
I've done some small programming where it attempts to find the slope of lines, and builds vectors from there, it works, however I would like to incorporate curves to smooth out the motion. I have no idea how to do that, and it seems to be a very difficult task.
I haven't tried making a vector/curved pathfinding algorithm to begin with, but the data input will be in grid points, so I don't know how efficient that would be.

This is pretty much a whole field of research. Maybe you would like something like http://hgoebl.github.io/simplify-java/ You could make an initial path using the pixel path, eg connect all of the centers, then simplify. I'm not sure if that includes splines for curves and such, but it depends on your usage.

First of all, I recommend you upgrade your path computation to a better algorithm, preferably LazyTheta*. This will make your pixelated path, that I'm assuming consists of many tiny pieces of multitudes of 45°, a much smoother any-angle path that approaches the actual geometric shortest path.
Then, to dive your robot smoothly, it is sufficient to pick a close-range goal from the computed path, a so called carrot, and steer the "donkey" towards the carrot with a pd controller. No need to explicitly compute curves (i.e. trajectories), which is rather difficult for non-holonomic vehicles. I'm providing an example of a pd controller below that is being used in production.
// This is a simple PD controller that computes steering commands towards
// the target q. The PD controller can be used for acceleration and for 
// velocity control, depending Only on how you interpret the output.
// I found that for velocity control only the p parameters are needed.
Vec2 UnicycleRobot::pdControlTo(const Vec2 &q) const
{
    // Tune these parameters to your system:
    double P_lin = 2.0;
    double D_lin = -0.1;
    double P_rot = 1.0;
    double D_rot = -0.1;

    Vec2 forward(1,0);
    double projectedTransErr = q * forward;
    double rotErr = forward.angleTo(q);
    double a = P_lin * projectedTransErr + D_lin * v;
    double b = P_rot * rotErr + D_rot * w;
    if (q.norm() < 0.01) // Dead band.
        return Vec2();
    return Vec2(a,b);
}

